# get last record of each user for each category

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to get the last record of each user for each category.

e.g I have a table

**tests (test_id,cat_id,user_id,score,time)**

I need each user last record for each category. I can use group by either category_id or by user_id but I am not getting how to get my desired result?

e.g I have following records

```
test_id | cat_id | user_id | score | time
      1 |      1 |      11 |    20 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      2 |      2 |      11 |    24 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      3 |      1 |      12 |    25 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      4 |      3 |      12 |    21 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      5 |      1 |      13 |    22 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      6 |      2 |      12 |    23 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      7 |      2 |      12 |    27 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      8 |      1 |      11 |    21 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
```

Now I need following result

```
test_id | cat_id | user_id | score | time
      2 |      2 |      11 |    24 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      3 |      1 |      12 |    25 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      4 |      3 |      12 |    21 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      5 |      1 |      13 |    22 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      7 |      2 |      12 |    27 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
      8 |      1 |      11 |    21 | 2016-11-12 01:11:11
```

In above o/p each user's only last result is coming of each category.

Comment: @Strawberry please check question now I hope you got what you need.

Comment: *"I can use group by either category_id or by user_id"* - `GROUP BY` doesn't help here. It doesn't fetch rows from the table. `GROUP BY` **generates** values using the values it reads from the table(s).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here we need a last user for all categories. SO we have to do group by category and find the user which have highest time for it.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tests t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT max(time) MaxTime,user_id,cat_id
    FROM tests
    GROUP BY user_id,cat_id
) t2
  ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  AND t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id
  AND t1.time = t2.MaxTime
order by t1.time desc
```

Comment: Nearly - but you forgot the user (or the cat) -FIXED

Comment: no it's not right we dont need last user we need all users of each category with last records

Comment: @user3110655 it's fixed now

Comment: @Strawberry Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure it's working or not because currently I have same time in time field and when I executed your query it is giving me wrong results it is giving me all results. Can't we do it with test_id which is auto incremented??

Comment: @user3110655 why not suck it and see - although if each combination of cat, user, and time is unique (as it surely is) then the problem you describe cannot be true

Comment: @Strawberry when I changed time in increasing order then it's working fine :) thanks for that but if possible can it be done with test_id as well?

Comment: @user3110655 You say *"I am not sure it's working or not because currently I have same time in time field and when I executed your query it is giving me wrong results it is giving me all results."* -- a correct query produces the correct results no matter the input data.

Answer (score 0):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT l.test_id, l.cat_id, l.user_id, l.score, l.time
FROM tests l                     # "l" from "last"
LEFT JOIN tests n                # "n" from "next"
    ON l.user_id = n.user_id     # match user
    AND l.cat_id = n.cat_id      # and category
    AND l.time <= n.time         # "next" is not before "last" (check the time)
    AND l.test_id < n.test_id    # "next" is after "last" when the times are equal
WHERE n.test_id IS NULL          # there is no "next" matching the JOIN conditions
```

#### How it works

The query joins `test` aliased as `l` (from "last") against itself aliased as `n` (from "next" after "last"). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that all the rows from `l` are included in the join. Each row from `l` is paired with all the rows from `n` that contain the same `user_id` and `cat_id` ("each user, each category") and have greater values in columns `time` and `test_id`. Because it's technically possible to have two rows with the same values in columns `user_id`, `cat_id` and `time`, on equal times match the row from `l` with a row from `n` that was input in the database later (it has a bigger auto-incremented `test_id`).

When a row that fulfills all the `ON` conditions is not found in `n`, the row from `l` is paired with a row full of `NULL`s.

The `WHERE` condition keeps only the rows having `NULL` in `n.test_id`. They are the rows from `l` that don't have a match in `n` (because there is no row in `n` having a bigger value in the `time` column or a bigger `test_id` when the times are equal). These are the last records for each (user, category) pair.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM tests GROUP BY cat_id`

Comment: Hi Zaid; your sql might be useful, but your answer would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed query would resolve the questioner's problem. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: It doesn't work properly if the records were not added to the database in the ascending order of their times. This is not an out-of-ordinary situation in a concurrent environment (the web, f.e.)

Comment: sorry, this answer refers to outdated question